# openpyxl - figuring out if a formula has array context in read_only mode

Tags: openpyxl

I want to figure out if a cell formula is called in array context or not. I understand from the openpyxl api, that I can use the `worksheet.formula_attributes` to get this info.

Unfortunately, this info is only available when `read_only=False` during load.

As performance for large files is of paramount importance to me, I cannot afford to load the file in `read_only=False`

I was hoping the Tokenizer would show the `{` and `}` in the formula but that's not the case.

Is there any other way to figure out if a formula was called in array context?

Comment: do you have an example code snipit of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You'll have to extend the libary yourself to do this.